# how to access models from another project in django?

Tags: python, django

I have this 2 project in my root directory.
One project is the admin website where it displays the message that it got from the callback server and the other one is the callback server of my bot message that collect the message to the models.
I want to access these models inside the callback server from the admin website which is the other project but I am confused how to do it?

I tried using the `PYTHONPATH` but it never showed the new file path that I add to the `PYTHONPATH`.

Can anyone give me a tip or suggestion how can I solve this problem? or doing this is not a best practice? thanks and here is my Django structure hopefully you guys can understand what is my problem and sorry my English is not that good :) thanks mate!.

```
/root
    /project1<-- my main website that display the message from callback server 
           /dashboard<-- apps
               admin.py
               models.py
               urls.py
               views.py
           manage.py

    /project2<-- callback server for bot message
           /bot<-- apps
               admin.py
               models.py
               urls.py
               views.py
           manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just create 1 project with 2 apps inside. This way the structure is nice you would not have to play around with python paths and importing from one app to the other is easy to do.

example

```
project1
    /dashboard<-- apps
               admin.py
               models.py
               urls.py
               views.py
    bot<-- apps
               admin.py
               models.py
               urls.py
               views.py
```

It not really the answer you are looking for but its helps with the readability of your structure and easy when using code from one app in the other.

if you really want them to be separate.

The other solution I can think of is the install project1 as a site package in project2 so that everything is available in project2 to be used.

Comment: that's what i done first but i want to try to separate this to two project so that it more safer what i meant by that is that  so only admin in admin network can access the website and the public network or client can send message to callback server and cant access the admin website <- i know i can  limit people for going over the website in django by using decorator or Django function  but i still want to know if there's by any chance a way to access the model from another project?

Comment: The other solution I can think of is the install project1 as a site package in project2 so that the model is available to be imported.